# How to declare typed Collection inside Symfony Entity in PHP 8.1

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpstan

I receive an error from PHPStan:

```
Property App\Entity\Product::$productArticles type mapping mismatch: property can contain Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection but database  
         expects Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection&iterable<App\Entity\ProductArticle>
```

My variable declaration:

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'product', targetEntity: ProductArticle::class)]
    /** @var  Collection<int, ProductArticle> */
    private Collection $productArticles;
```

How can I use both: annotation to declare variable for ORM and PHPDoc comment to declare Collection type?

Comment: Have you tried moving ORM annotation into PHPDock _after_ `@var  Collection<int, ProductArticle>`?

Comment: You mean something like this?

https://pastebin.com/raw/7RxJC64J

It... works. But looks terrible to me.

Comment: Use old syntax `@ORM\OneToMany`. And you want working code or to look pretty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHPDoc needs to be above the attribute.

```php
class Foo
{
    /** @var  Collection<int, ProductArticle> */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'product', targetEntity: ProductArticle::class)]
    private Collection $productArticles;
}
```

This is a bug with the parser library (`nikic/php-parser`) PHPStan uses. So it has to be this way for now.